# Varying speed of shaft Spectral Kurtosis

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, time-frequency

I want to perform Spectral Kurtosis (Kurtogram) on 10-second vibration signal of 25.6 kHz sample rate, where the shaft is varying in speed.

Will a preprocessing step of resampling the signal be necessary (upsamling; so that there is an equal amount of samples within each shaft rotation), or will the SK handle the non-stationary behaviour?

I'm using [Matlab's kurtogram implementation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/kurtogram.html):

> *"The fast kurtogram algorithm uses bandpass filtering along with a
> simplified computation to approximate the spectral kurtosis for each
> window size and frequency.*

**Update**

(The kurtogram looks much better on the resampled signal, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach.)
[image]

The objective is to diagnose the health of a bearing by first applying an optimal band-pass filter based on SK. After that, I wish to find the enveloped signal. Then, I want to decompose the filtered signal using EEMD to look for fault characteristics. The bearing is on an operating wind turbine.

Much like this paper: [Faulty bearing signal recovery from large noise using a hybrid method on spectral kurtosis and ensemble empirical mode decomposition](https://www.cityu.edu.hk/seam/Web%20Content/Papers/Faulty%20bearing%20signal%20recovery%20from%20large%20noise%20using%20a%20hybrid%20method%20based%20on%20spectral%20kurtosis%20and%20ensemble%20empirical%20mode%20decomposition.pdf)

Comment: It all depends on what the objective for using kurtosis is. Is it possible to provide some more information around the problem?

Comment: @A_A added some information now.

Answer (score 1):

Resampling the signal to the shaft cycle domain wrong as with equalization of the sampling rate for the stationary components within the signal you are smearing the transfer function response.

In case you need to handle this problem, you can [resample the spectrogram](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S088832701500446X) similarly to the one presented here [image]

Nevertheless, Kurtogram and spectral kurtosis are pretty tolerant to mild shaft speed variation. For the assumptions, you may read the following [ref](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0888327004001517).